# IText: registering font: not found as file or resource

Tags: fonts, itext, registering

I am developing on windows plattform. My maven project has the following structure for font resources:

```
src/main/resources/package/name/fonts
```

I try to register a font as following:

```
FontFactory.register("package/name/fonts/fontname.otf");
```

But I get the error:

```
package/name/fonts/fontname.otf not found as file or resource
```

What is my failure?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I get the correct path with getResource():

```
String pathtofont = "/package/name/fonts/fontname.otf";
String fontname = myworkingclass.class.getResource(pathtofont).toString();
```

then I get it registerd:

```
FontFactory.register(fontname);
```

Important is that the path to font starts with a /.